# How to register Source Tree on Mac?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I want to import the license for SourceTree. Atlassian saying that I should register first and then import the license.

[image]

But I cannot find the registration function on the menu bar.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlassian changed the process in the latest release of SourceTree (2.2 for Mac). Launch SourceTree for the first time and you'll see a prompt to log in. Have or get an Atlassian account (it's free), log in and that's it. [Announcement](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2016/02/22/sourcetree-update-atlassian-account-git-lfs-support-ui-refresh-and-more/):

> Gone are the days of being prompted to register after 30 days,
>   download a license file, license multiple copies for more than one
>   machine or figure out a way to license SourceTree for your whole team.
>   Upon updating to the latest SourceTree, log in once and you’re done.

Comment: This is super unclear on Atlassian's website, I'm going round in circles trying to register source tree.

Comment: Click on the link that says "Go to atlassian's webpage" in the startup window of Sourcetree and it takes you to a page where you can download the license document, with the text in the question, i.e. that you should add the license by going to the non-existent "Source Tree > Registration" in the menu bar.